# Java Stream to String[] Array

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm reading from a CSV file with a structure like this:

```
1;Miller Hame; 1,2,3,4,5.....; 1232323;
```

I have to split it to `String[]`, I could work with every line and there with every `"Part"`

My Code so far:

```
Stream<String> input = java.nio.file.Files.lines(java.nio.file.Paths.get("data.csv"));

String[] lines = input.skip(1)
        .map(s->s.split(";"))
        .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Actually I'm getting `java.lang.ArrayStoreException`.

(Yes, it's for homework, but I don't want the whole solution, only for this very small part of the work.)

Comment: You have a `String[][]` not a `String[]`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider yes, replacing `.toArray(String[]::new);` with `.toArray(String[][]::new);` should work.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this

```
Stream<String> input = Files.lines(Paths.get("src/data.csv"));

String[][] lines = input.skip(1)
        .map(s -> s.split(";"))
        .toArray(String[][]::new);
```

Advice:
You don't have to type full path for a class. You can import it. This is for `Files` and `Paths` classes

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
```